# ContainerRequestFilter method not being called

Tags: java, web-services, rest, jersey, apache-tomee

I've just started learning how to code REST web services, and I've been stuck with this for several days now. I'm coding an example application with header-based filtering, using Jersey 2 and deployed on Tomee-plus 1.7.2. No matter what I try, the ContainerRequestFilter's *filter* method is never called.

```
// TestRequestFilter.java
import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestContext;
import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestFilter;
import javax.ws.rs.container.PreMatching;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider;

@Provider
@PreMatching
public class TestRequestFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter
{
    private final static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(DemoRESTRequestFilter.class.getName());

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestCtx) throws IOException
    {
        System.out.println("FILTER-REQUEST");
    }
}
```

My *web.xml* file is empty save for the required headers. The behavior right now is: the filter is recognised as @Provider and instantiated as normal, the test web service I have (just a GET returning an empty Response) can be called normally, but the *filter* method is never called.

Things I've tried and their effects:

- Declare the filter in a class extending Application: Error on deployment.
- Register the filter in a class extending ResourceConfig: Filter is instantiated twice, but *filter* method is still not called.
- Use the classes from the com.sun.jersey.spi.container package: No effect.
- Add an authentication annotation (@RolesAllowed, @PermitAll,...) to the WS method: No effect.
- Add *disabled=true* to *cfx-rs.properties* in server configuration: Deployed service cannot be found at usual URL.
- Add this to *web.xml*: No effect.

```html
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>CongressAppWS</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>  
  <init-param>
    <param-name>org.glassfish.jersey.spi.container.ContainerRequestFilters</param-name>
    <param-value>com.s4w.congressapp.auth.DemoRESTRequestFilter;com.s4w.congressapp.auth.DemoRESTResponseFilter</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>  
    <param-value>com.s4w.congressapp.auth;com.s4w.congressapp.resources</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

- Using *com.sun.jersey.spi.container* prefix instead of *org.glassfish.jersey.spi.container* in previous code: No effect.

I'm honestly running out of options here. Every time I try something new, either there is no effect or everything stops working. Any help?

Comment: Did you do anything special to configure TomEE to use Jersey? It already has a CXF implementation. Can you find any signs that Jersey is actually being used, and not CXF? If CXF is being uses, AFAIK, that version of TomEE uses a CXF version that is only compatible with JAX-RS 1.1 and not 2.0. 2.0 is the version with the `ContainerRequestFilter`.

Comment: The only thing I tried was what I stated, that I added a *disabled=true* in the *cfx-rs.properties* config file. I suppose this does as you say, disable the Tomee CXF implementation, but when I do this, I no longer can reach the webservices at any URL that I can think of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an alternative to *ContainerRequestFilter* that actually works! It's **javax.servlet.Filter**. Extending from this class, all I had to do was annotate it with the following code and the filtering mechanism works like a charm.

```
@WebFilter(filterName = "AuthenticationFilter", urlPatterns = { "/*" })
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this is that `ContainerRequestFilter` is part JAX-RS 2.0, but TomEE 1.7.X comes with JAX-RS 1.1. You'll either have to upgrade TomEE to 7.0.0+ or use a different Server (e.g. Glassfish).

Comment: It's been a long time, and I've since moved to plain Tomcat, but thanks for the insight ;)